# What is the use of Generate thumbnails option on Site Settings item for XM Cloud SXA site definition?

Tags: xm-cloud

I can see following setting on site settings for XM Cloud SXA sites site definition item.
"Generate thumbnails"

Cannot find anything in the documentation also related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the answer that I got from the Sitecore support 2 weeks ago.

Thumbnails are to be displayed instead of default icons while you select a page in Pages editor, and also in Explorer.
In case enabled for a website, Sitecore (re)generates a thumbnail for a page on each item save.

**How to disable it?**

You can disable generation of thumbnails on on three levels:

1. For a page:
   Each SXA page has 'Generate Thumbnails' field on it under Appearance standard section
2. For your website, via the field on site grouping item.
   By default this should be disabled.
3. In Sitecore.ThumbnailGenerator.config configuration file, for a whole instance.

Answer (score 0):

It generates a thumbnail for every item you create.
e.g if you create a rendering it will generate a thumbnail for it, if you add a field in a template it will create the template for it